# Use or not use CoreData in an App that syncs transactions?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am a beginner and I have this little debate with my friend who is a Ruby and rails developer with more than five years experience, and has worked basically for the web, and I know the information he gets is from various presentations he have been to.

So, I am learning and bulding a project in the way. This project needs to get data from other devices and also send data from the administrator devices for the other users.

I want to build this app to be able to save data if the device for some reason is offline (the user will travel, and can find himself out of signal).

My friend says that I do not need t save data into the device, or not use CoreData, that I probably need some type of cache to save the data temporarily while the device is offline.

I tell him that this is not like a weather app where you only download the data and show it to the user, I need to make changes to the data and send it back to the server, so other users see the change.

So, my question is:

Do I need to use CoreData to save data locally when the device is offline and send a request to the serve parsing JSON?

Which is the best approach?

Thank you very much for your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My friend says that I do not need t save data into the device, or not use CoreData, that I probably need some type of cache to save the data temporarily while the device is offline.

Where does your friend think the cache will be located if it isn't on the device? Caching but not saving data are contradictory ideas.

Core Data can be useful as an offline cache. There are other options, including saving property list files and using SQLite directly. Which one is best depends heavily on how you'll need to use the data in the app.

> Do I need to use CoreData to save data locally when the device is offline, or use CoreData to save everything and send a request to the server using parse JSON file?

Keeping in mind that we don't have a detailed description of your app,

- If the server provides JSON-formatted data, then you need to parse that.
- If you want to use the data offline, you need to save it on the device somehow. Whether you call this a cache or not is meaningless.
- Core Data is one possible approach. It might or might not be the right one, but that's a separate question that can't be answered without a lot more information about how your app uses this data.

A common approach would be to request data from the server and save it locally. When accessing data in the app, look it up in the local copy. Keep server communication and local data access separate; if they're the same thing then you're talking to the server directly for all data and have no offline access. Keep track of local changes so you can send them back to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Tom, I really appreciate it!